# Apache : Rewrite rule to change a file path

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I need to change a jpg path to point to a different picture in a website. This has to be done through the apache conf because the website is always updated with git.

The point is to help the developers to easily see they are working on which dev environment, so if I can rewrite the path a the main logo to something else in their home that would be perfect.

I tried to add this in the VirtualHost configuration:
RewriteRule ^/img/logo.jpg /home/someUser/logo2.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<Directory /path/to/documentroot/>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^img/logo.jpg$ path/to/logo2.jpg
</Directory>
```

path/to/logo2.jpg must be under the document root (So in your example /home/someUser/ should be the document root of the site). You can't create rewrite rules to files above the document root (I.E. if your root is /var/www/html/ you couldn't create a rewrite rule to /var/www/hello.html)

Comment: I get this error : RewriteBase: only valid in per-directory config files

Comment: Oh I assumed you would be putting this in a .htaccess file. I'll update the code to show you the directory based config.

Comment: When I go directly to the image, for example: http://www.myWebsite.ca/img/logo.jpg, i'm not redirected to /img/logo2.jpg

Comment: You shouldn't be redirected, rewrites are server-side so on the frontend the URL won't change. If you want it to change add `[R=301]` to the end of the `RewriteRule` line

Comment: As a side note, your answer helped me understand how to tell Apache I need it to use a `.conf` file instead of a lot of `.htaccess` files. Specifically, with `Zend Framework` I managed to create this file `apache/conf/extras/httpd-zf.conf` which includes the same rewrite rules I had in those .htaccess using as you said the `<Directory/path/to/documentroot>` also listed in the VirtualHost config file.
THANKS!!! You helped me a lot! I wish this hint can help somebody ;)